# Rails ActiveAdmin active_admin_form_for submit button disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin, disabled-input

I have a form where has many nested forms with submit button for each. I want to disable some submit buttons according to a certain condition. but I couldn't find such property.

Here is my code:

```
active_admin_form_for [:activeadmin, @some_obj], {
    url: {action: 'some_action'}, method: :patch
  } do |f|
    f.inputs 'Some Name' do
      f.li "some html".html_safe
    end

  f.actions do
    f.action :submit, label: 'Update'
  end
end
```

I tired the following but nothing worked:

`f.action :submit, label: 'Update', disabled: true`

`f.action :submit, label: 'Update', input_html: {readonly: :true}`

`f.action :submit, label: 'Update', input_html: {disabled: :true}`

`f.action :submit, label: 'Update', button_html: {disabled: true}`

`f.action :submit, label: 'Update', button_html: {readonly: true}`

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

`f.action` accepts `button_html` argument to apply HTML attributes - [refer](https://github.com/formtastic/formtastic/blob/69a01f0b5654cf46b4067a35ee7845afbd6daee4/lib/formtastic/actions/button_action.rb#L53)

```
f.action :submit, label: 'Update', button_html: { disabled: true }
```

Comment: @AhmedSalah could you please inspect the button on browser and see if the disabled attribute is getting applied or not. I just tried it on my app and its working for me.

Comment: here is how the element looks `<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Update" disabled="disabled" data-disable-with="Update">`

Comment: looks ok to me. Is there any action performed when you click on that button?

Comment: yes it's the form submit button as stated